# Does AWS API Gateway support OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I read somewhere in the documentation that AWS API Gateway includes support for Swagger, but Swagger is now more formally known as the OpenAPI specification and has been bumped to major version 3.0.

Comment: Relevant forum thread on AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=799038&tstart=0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AWS API Gateway supports OpenAPI 3.0 since September 27, 2018, both during API import and export:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-api-gateway-adds-support-for-openapi-3-api-specification/

Comment: Be aware there is an extensive list of unsupported features: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis

Answer (score 9):

There is a list of tooling that is being built for V3 here https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md

To my knowledge AWS don't have anything yet.  Also, they are one of the few large tech companies that haven't joined the OAI. https://www.openapis.org/membership/members